# Issue trying to implement stacked LSTM layers with Keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to add more LSTM layers to my neural net, but I keep getting the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have 2 dimensions, but got array with shape (385, 128, 1)
```

The code for my model is as follows:

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(60, return_sequences=True, input_shape=(128, 14)))

model.add(LSTM(60, return_sequences=False))

model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(data_train, RUL_train, epochs=number_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose=1)
```

It works fine when I remove the second LSTM layer. Or if I add more dense layers. Just not when I add the LSTM layer. RUL_train has shape (385, 128, 1).
The output of model.summary is as follows:

```
_________________________________________________________________
   Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
lstm_15 (LSTM)               (None, 128, 60)           18000     
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_16 (LSTM)               (None, 60)                29040     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_7 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 61        
=================================================================
Total params: 47,101
Trainable params: 47,101
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Which version of Keras are you using?

Comment: `return_sequences=True` on last layer

Answer (score 1):

Your labels array has three dimensions: `(385,128,1)`.

So, what is your purpose?

- Classify all steps in each sequence? - All LSTMs must use `return_sequence=True`
- One class for the entire sequence? - Fix your labels array somehow to be `(samples,1)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug that was introduced in Keras 2.1.0 (and wasn't completely fixed in 2.1.1). Try installing Keras 2.0.9 or earlier:

```
pip uninstall keras
pip install keras==2.0.9
```

https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/8481

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I was actually running Keras 2.0.8. But I tried updating to 2.0.9 anyway and I'm still encountering the same issue.